# join list of data frames by specific columns and row

Tags: r, dataframe

I have 12 months of stock data contained in a list of 12 data frames. Each data frame has the following structure:

```
    'data.frame':   218680 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ Symbol        : Factor w/ 3423 levels "AABC","AACB",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ MktCategory   : Factor w/ 4 levels " NR - Non-Market Maker Reporting Member",..: 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ TSO           : Factor w/ 3352 levels ""," C - ECN",..: 745 745 745 745 745 745 745 745 745 745 ...
 $ TSO_Date      : Factor w/ 180 levels "","01/12/2005",..: 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 159 ...
 $ X.OfMP        : int  4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
 $ MPID          : Factor w/ 739 levels "","ABLE","ABNA",..: 590 668 292 306 313 587 100 681 432 598 ...
 $ MP_type       : Factor w/ 4 levels "","C","M","NR": 3 2 3 3 3 3 2 4 3 3 ...
 $ Total_Vol     : int  0 0 0 0 60000 0 300 2184 0 0 ...
 $ Total_Rank    : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 4 3 0 0 ...
 $ Total_Pct     : int  0 0 0 0 92 0 0 3 0 0 ...
 $ Block_Vol     : int  0 0 0 0 55000 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Block_Rank    : int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ Block_Pct     : int  0 0 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ YTD_Total_Vol : int  100 900 100 2200 124541 18429 10700 7732 13600 200 ...
 $ YTD_Total_Rank: int  16 10 16 9 1 3 5 6 4 14 ...
 $ YTD_Total_Pct : int  0 0 0 0 54 8 5 3 6 0 ...
 $ YTD_Block_Vol : int  0 0 0 0 117500 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ YTD_Block_Rank: int  0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ YTD_Block_Pct : int  0 0 0 0 100 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

I want to combine all of the data frames into 1 data frame where it lists each symbol as the first column, and the rest of the columns only being the Total_Vol and Total_Rank associated with that Symbol from the individual months. Kind of like this:

Symbol  Total_Vol(month1)   Total Rank(month 1) Total_Vol(month2)  Total_Rank(month2) ...

AACC    ...
AACE    ....
AAON    ...
AAPL
AATI
AAUK
ABAX
ABCB
ABCO
ABCW

Comment: `?join_all` from `plyr` is one option. Something like `plyr::join_all(list(df1[c('Symbol','Total_vol','Total_rank')], df2[c('Symbol','Total_vol','Total_rank')], df3[c('Symbol','Total_vol','Total_rank')]), by = 'Symbol')` maybe

Comment: hey thanks for the answer, do you want to post this as an answer so i can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

This should probably work.

```
install.packages('plyr')
library(plyr)

df_list <- list(df_1[c('Symbol','Total_vol','Total_rank')], 
                df_2[c('Symbol','Total_vol','Total_rank')], 
                df_3[c('Symbol','Total_vol','Total_rank')])

join_all(df_list, by = 'Symbol')
```